# Property cannot be found on forward class object?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a UIView and I'm trying to set its layer properties.

```
self.colorSwatch = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(400, 150, 100, 100)];
self.colorSwatch.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
```

However, when I try to access the `.layer.cornerRadius` property, I get a warning that says "Property 'cornerRadius' cannot be found in forward class object 'CALayer *'.

What does this mean? Thanks

Answer (score 101, accepted):

It doesn't know what type of object the `layer` property is.  Add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to the top of your file.

Comment: You also need to add the **QuartzCore** framework if you didn't do that already.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the file #import < QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> in ViewController.m class if and only if xcode version is less than 5.

See if you are using xcode version 5 or latest than that then not required to import  .It is automatically included.