# Property 'cornerRadius' cannot be found in forward class object 'CALayer'

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, calayer

I've gone through all the answers that are related to this error (nearly all of them suggests [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829371/property-cannot-be-found-on-forward-class-object)) however my problem seems to be different.
I want to have a rounded rectangle UIButton with particular image as background. I manage to do that successfully in one of my view controller, let's call this VC as `first VC`, by using:

```
self.revealAnswerButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
```

In this VC, first VC, I've only imported `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` and Not `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`. And this works fine. I guess this is because:

Q1. UIView Class has `@property layer` that I'm using in above code so it is working fine without even importing `Quartz` Framework. Is my this assumption right?

Let's move on: in my other VC, let's call this as second VC, in same StoryBoard same code (`self.startButton.layer.cornerRadius`) doesn't work. It throws error:
`Property 'cornerRadius' cannot be found in forward class object 'CALayer'`

Q2. Why is this different behavior in different VCs?

I tried to find root cause and this is what I've found:
In my first VC `layer` property is mapping directly to UIView's `@property layer` like this:

[image: Property 'cornerRadius' cannot be found in forward class object 'CALayer']

but in my second VC `layer` is routing to `+layer` class method of `CALayer` like this:

[image: CALayer class method layer]

I don't know where to go from here :( Can you please help me out? Thanks a lot for your time. Please let me know if any other info is required. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, can't you just add <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> to whatever class/viewcontroller you need to do corner radius?

Comment: Import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> into your second controller's .m file.

Comment: @SaurabhIf you are getting warning like Property 'cornerRadius' cannot be found in forward class object 'CALayer', it means you need to add QuartzCore framework.

Comment: after going through all the above jugglery I tried adding Quartz framework as well to my second VC. That curbed the error for sure but didn't round the button. So I thought that I'll sort out this issue first and if this doesn't work then adding Quartz again and checking why button in not getting round with `cornerRadius`. Thanks a lot for your quick responses.

Comment: The first layer property is just a forwarded class, the second VC knows about the class definition. Are the 2 buttons from the difference VC's of the same type and class?

Comment: @RobvanderVeer Yes, both the buttons are `UIButton`s. What do you mean by type? I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: As i see it, one VC includes QuartzCore.h for you (direct or indirect). Nothing special. As the other poster says, just include  Quartzcore and stop wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

you have to import  to viewcontroller you are using corner radius.
and for making corener round use the following

```
self.revealAnswerButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
self.revealAnswerButton.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: I can import `Quartz` framework and can use `cornerRadius` and `masksToBounds` to achieve the same but in my first VC am not importing Quartz and just importing `UIKit` and it works fine in first VC. so whats different in second VC. thats the question? Thanks for your time.

Comment: check your first VC .h and .m file you might be importing some other classes in which you might have defined Quartz classes, so your first VC get Quartz classes indirectly through some other classes.

Comment: I've checked that thing but none of the imported classes indirectly uses `Quartz`. Here is my question 1 form above: UIView Class has `@property layer` that I'm using in above code so it is working fine without even importing Quartz Framework. Is my this assumption right?

Comment: You need to import QuartCore to access properties of CALayer

Comment: I managed to do this without importing QuartzCore framework in my first VC. But same throws error in second VC. That's my dilemma.

Comment: almost every component has layer property, so it is not working because of that. for testing find out all the classes where you are importing Quartz and remove them and then check is it still working for VC1?

Comment: @Parser I didn't even have QuartzCore in my linked frameworks and libraries in my app and it worked fine in my first VC. I just had default frameworks added.